# Find the key hash for a signed app

Tags: android, keystore, keytool, hashtag

I have signed my app and exported it to a folder on my desktop called app in this folder is my app itself and the keystore. How do i find the key hash that i can copy into the facebook developers page. i have openssl installed but cant seem to generate the key hash ive tried many other threads on stack and none have seemed to help, thanks

James

Comment: ive seen that but it didnt work, just says keytool is an invalid command

Comment: so find keytool ..... with google ... > Java SDK

Comment: what do you mean? I really dont know what im doing, i just want this to work on my phone

Comment: install java SDK ... it contains tool named keytool, tool ... to many tools(in one sentence) ... and yeah you should also download openssl tools(avoiding next question about "openssl invalid command")

Comment: will each app i create have a different hashkey or will it be the same?

Comment: about keytool again: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe .... it depends on you ... if you signing all app with the same key one hashkey is enough

Comment: i have got the keytool :) but still no luck, i also do have openssl installed, is the key generated on the keystore for the app i just created?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

1. You should know where is your keystore file. For me is `C:\Users\Selvin\Desktop\selvin.kp`
2. You should know your alias in keystore. For me is `selvin`
3. You should know path to keytool. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe`
4. You should know path to openssl. `C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe`
5. You should know password to keystore. For me is ***** hehe

Then, you should call:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selvin -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64

Replace my path and alias with proper ones.

Then you should see:

> Enter keystore password:

Enter your password and you should get something like this: `NfhDlIH7XWJzUZRjL+pZySrMX1Q=`

**EDITED**: `NfgDlIG7XWJzUZRUL+bZySrMX1Q=` <- is a bad hash. Or you got so lucky that your key made the same collision as

> error:keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias  does not exist

If hash not working:

First, call

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias selvin -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp

Type password and read the error

If you don't remember your alias `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <selvinn> does not exist` I used selvinn to show error.

For a list of all your entries/aliases:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe -list -keystore c:\users\selvin\desktop\selvin.kp

**second edit**

[image]

Comment: What is the alias meant to be? or doesnt it matter?

Comment: see my edit it should be the same that you use to signed app in eclipse

Comment: Thanks a lot. If you are on mac, keytool and openssl are already installed. (just use keytool .... | openssl ...)

Comment: Your one line (bad hash) saved my life, remainded me to check my alias in command, can sleep in peace now, thanks! :D

Comment: Where do I call this line? This answer is not complete at all

Comment: Works! Also, you can get the info later using: keytool -list -keystore "path\to\debug.keystore"

Answer (score 22):

For those still struggling I have found that these steps when followed correctly will certainly work but they can be quite challenging to get right first time, and actually I have found that sometimes the base64 conversion of the fingerprint when dealing with some alias' do not work (the hash gets truncated for some reason).  I've written various batch files that pull most of these instructions already mentioned together so I don't rule out a problem there.

However, essentially most people fall down at the openssl stage (either can't find it, don't know how to use it, or Windows piping doesn't correctly chain the output from the SHA1 export to the base64 conversion input).

To get around this you can use an alternative method which is probably easier to follow and understand.  Essentially what the facebook API wants is the base64 representation (encoding) of the SHA1 hash used to fingerprint your APK.  To do this you can just list the keystore:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\JRE6\Bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore "Path-to-your-keystore" -storepass "KeystorePassword" > somefile.txt
```

Obviously you need to change the path to the keytool executable according to your own setup, and replace "Path-to-your-keystore" and "KeystorePassword" with your keystore path and password!  The result should be the creation of a file "sometext.txt" in the current folder which you can then open in any text editor.  The text file will list all of the keystore alias' and their respective MD5 and SHA1 hashes as hex strings.

Now just find the alias used to sign your APK, copy the SHA1 hash, and use any online hex to base64 converter to convert it to the base64 encoding format that facebook requires.  You can find an online converter by googling "online hex to base64 converter".  I've been using [this one](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en) as you can just copy and paste the string right from the text file in to the box provided and it will just remove the colons that separate each hex byte.

One final point (somewhat obvious but..) only copy and paste the hex string and NOT the SHA1: prefix!

Hope this helps someone; it certainly works for me!

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely helpful.  You mention that the base64 conversion sometimes doesn't work properly - any more detail on fixing that so that the online converter isn't needed?

Comment: sorry to resurrect, but what SHA1 i got is this

`SHA1: 3C:FB:ED:25:2A:48:D4:D9:E6:11:CA:B6:E2:8A:80:7C:FE:68:7D:71`

Answer (score 14):

First i would like to thank Selvin!

This answer is almost identical to Selvin's answer but it still took me 3 hours to get it to work :P so a little more tutorial for the real newbs

How to get a hashKey from a keystore

- first install OpenSSL from google code and put it in your C:\ folder
  [download link](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/)
- find keytool program location (default in java
  folder)
- find keystore location (there is a debug default value)

location keytool C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.xxx)\bin\keytool
location openssl C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\OpenSSL
location (debug)keystore C:\Users[usernamepc].android\debug.keystore

open cmd in windows(start->run->cmd) and navigate to the keytool location
or copy paste the following string, note that you can’t use ctrl+v but right mouseclick

```
cd c:\program files (x86)\java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin
```

when in the right directory paste this string in the cmd line:

```
keytool.exe -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore c:\users\charx\.android\debug.keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64
```

"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl" is the path of opensssl.exe replace it with your openssl.exe's path

make sure that you change the [usernamepc] of yourto the name of your pc as you can see in my case it’s charx. Also the directory for the java jdk xxxx depends on your version.

cmd should show hashkey

hash key for my debug file is

```
h1GdQbgB8b/liCG+acmZWkgIRHA=
```

Answer (score 9):

A solution with Eclipse (for lazy people like me).

Select any project in Eclipse, Export - Android Application, enter your key pass etc. and on the last page at the bottom you will see 
MD5: ....
SHA1:....

Copy the SHA1 string and paste it in any HEX-Base64 online converter (for example this one: http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php)

Congrats! You've got the key hash needed for Facebook Dev Console.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions mentioned above didn't work for me for some reason but i was able to successfully generate keyhash. I am writing the 10 easiest step to get keyhash of your signed apk **[apk signed with keystore]**:

1. Copy the below code into your `activity [start Activity]`.This code should be contained in your activity so that you can extract the proper keyhash when your signed apk's Activity starts.

   ```
   private void getHashKey() {
   try {
       PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
               getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
       for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
           MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
           md.update(signature.toByteArray());
           Log.e("MY_KEY_HASH:",
                   Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
       }
   } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   } }
   ```
2. Your `AndroidManifest.xml` file should have the attribute `android:allowBackup="true"` in its application tag.
3. Export your signed apk and Install the app in your mobile phone and then connect your phone in debugging mode with `usb debugging on`.
4. Then go to `sdk\platform-tools`
5. Open command prompt and type `adb devices` to see whether your device is connected or not. if device not listed then try to fix that issue before continuing to next step.
6. Then type `adb logcat >"log.txt"`. Your `cmd` screen will like hanged.
   Dont Panic. Its Perfectly normal as the whole logcat is being written to `log.txt`.
7. Run your app and hopefully when you think that the `getHashKey()`
   function is executed then press `ctrl+c` on command prompt to end log file writing.
8. Now the command prompt will become responsive again. Now go into
   your `sdk\platform-tools` dir and you will see that a log.txt file
   has been created which contains logs.
9. Now open it in a `texteditor` and search for `MY_KEY_HASH:`"-----------Your keyhash-------"
10. Copy this onto your `FB account` or whereever you need it and then make another build in which the `android:allowBackup="false"` and `getHashKey()` function is
     removed.

Hope this helped everyone :)

Comment: You could also just monitor the logcat output in android studio and search for "MY_KEY_HASH" to save a few steps

Answer (score 3):

I couldnt be bothered with all this I see what the facebook sdk is actually sending by
exporting my signed App with temp code in place to display facebook error.toString()
in Authorize which gives the hash key its looking for I then put this in my facebook App and bingo !

Comment: Yeah I did this, except the logcat was showing the key when facebook was failing. Took about 1 minute to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you use your alies use this command to find keystore alies

> keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks | findstr "Alias Creation"