# Can`t get my keyhash for Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook

Ok , I read this

[Find the key hash for a signed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803944/find-the-key-hash-for-a-signed-app)

which is a good help, but when I try to run my full command line

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyAlias -keystore C:\Users\Luiz Aurio\Desktop\Java Project\Android\Mykeystore.kp | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\Users\Luiz Aurio\Desktop\Java Project\opencss\bin\openssl base64
```

I receive this error message

"The input line is too long"

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\trainee\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

or

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey  -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\trainee\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```