# Android : debug keystore

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I am trying to get hash key for facebook (Native Android App) login using following command

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Combitech\.android\debug.keystore"
```

I have entered password "android" but instead of hash key i got some output like follow

```
☺☺♂♣ 071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
431004061248Z071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
☺☺☺♣ ♥é☺☼ 0é☺0é☺"0
☺☺♂♣ ♥é☺☺ I$F╠≥C½?k½~U▬éïP▄ûπ^?╢Äïï▲D╓♣╥h☺⌡═Æ╠■≥        ,♦Wm#≥W▓♦↓┴1¡┼╩ú♀⌠,-62º ═V¶■‼   ûªE¢⌂φg╢çpSúuαΩ√:ôp∩<û╕úxj↓╠G♠=↔x ╥s0²↓¬}é←êR╜s╜↓■6║/6HεC≥Éq1J═α┐3í2PU╓i-←ë¿Φαπ°Åφε÷àX░R‼   ☺Lje      -w╘²L▲♣╧♦'7←âDτ╜
╤Ω▲£6uü░K■o↕ö§q┼6▌⌂(≡}º3EC┴bo>√ßS─▌a«¼╡τ▐ïñºñ¢._w]¥±▒0'σ√»?oÄ╙⌠X»C█2â1)√7zod
```

Any one have any idea how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want to get the SHA1,MD5 keys ?

Comment: I want to get Key Hashes for Native Android App.

Answer (score 1):

To show the SHA1 hash (you need for Google APIs) and all other hashes use this command instead:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Combitech\.android\debug.keystore"
```

Comment: for anyone on a Mac the path to the Android debug keystore is ~/.android/debug.keystore

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for may be:

`"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Combitech\.android\debug.keystore" | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64`

*Tips:*

- Better use full path of `keytool.exe` location and also full path of `openssl`.
- Do not forget to change the keystore path with your path `"C:\Users\Combitech\.android\debug.keystore"`

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923354/944070)

Comment: fixed with your keystore alias and pathfilename

Answer (score 0):

You can get both MD5 fingerprint and SHA1 fingerprint from your eclipse itself. Try this :

Windows > Preferences > Android > Build

Note that there will be two different keys one will be default and another for your custom keystore used for app development.

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below. And also make sure you debug keystore file is correct.

You should add `'-v'` to your keytool command. A `-v` to your command will get fingerprints in MD5, SHA1 and SHA256.

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Combitech\.android\debug.keystore
```

You don't need to add the double quotes on the debug.keystore file path.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.It will return hash key in your log cat.
and dont forget to change the package name

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.example.package", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your package name here
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.v("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        }
```