# Can't Login with Facebook with Firebase

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an application that features logging in with facebook. I used Firebase, and followed the instructions exactly from the [home page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login?authuser=0).
When logged in I got the error pictured, I tried to fix it by 'Add Platform' on the Facebook Control Panel. But my app is growing so it can not have a package name on Google Play.
I tried to create a hash key by the way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803944/find-the-key-hash-for-a-signed-app). But it returns non isSuccessful () result.

[image]

Comment: You can add your own package. It's not necessary to have a package name of PlayStore. Have you checked `Add Platform`?

Comment: Show the code how you got there

Comment: @MosheEdri that kind of error is generally when the application is not correctly configured on Facebook Developer's Console.

Comment: I think it's in Facebook dashboard as well but without the code you wouldn't know for sure

Comment: This error suggest that he didn&#39;t even configured an app so it could be the app secret that he is missing

Comment: Sorry, but I've added Platform with project package before, it looks like all they do is work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use auth0 with facebook you need add the APP domain into facebook app there are config.xml file and the domain is something like that `<widget id="com.dutytask.enlaceit" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">`

Just add the id attribute value into `Android package name` field.
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I've added before, it looks like all they do is work

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the URL from Facebook Sign-In Method in Firebase Console correctly copied to Facebook's Developer Portal Facebook Login Settings as a Valid OAuth redirect URI.

It's not required for your app to be available on the Google Play Store in order to use the package name to setup the Native Android integration in Facebook's Developer portal. It's the best way to integrate Facebook Login after all. You can find your Package Name in your build.gradle file as applicationId.